# How to draw an editable and draggable pentagon and find if any point lies inside it or not?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck with an issue related to drawing editable and draggable pentagon using google api.

Issue: When I try to edit the polygon, its point keeps on increasing. But I need it to be fixed as 5 points.

**Code:**

```
Poly1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    Path: redCoords,
    fillColor:"#FF0000", 
    fillOpacity:0.2,
    strokeColor:"#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity:1.0,
    strokeWeight:1,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true
});
```

Actual requirement is:

I have to allow user to draw up to maximum 10 pentagons (Editable and Draggable), and then accordingly I need to find whether my point is inside a polygon.

Comment: You'd have to set `editable` to false.  Then add your own markers at each of the vertices. Allow these to be draggable.  Have an event listener for when the user finishes dragging them, that updates your polygon path to point to the new coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some working code which creates a 5-sided polygon, with markers on each coordinate.  The polygon itself isn't editable... when the user drags one of the markers, we redraw the polygon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Draggable polygons</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: {lat: 51.476706, lng: 0},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        });

        // create an array of coordinates for a pentagonal polygon
        var arrCoords = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.474821, -0.001935),
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.474647, 0.003966),
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.477708, 0.004073),
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.479753, 0.000468),
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.477654, -0.002192)
        ];

        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: arrCoords,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map
        });

        // add a marker at each coordinate
        for (var i = 0; i < arrCoords.length; i++) {
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: arrCoords[i],
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });

            bindMarker(marker, arrCoords, i, polygon);
        }
    }

    function bindMarker(marker, arrCoords, i, polygon) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
            // update the coordinates of the corresponding point in the polygon path
            arrCoords[i] = e.latLng;
            polygon.setPath(arrCoords);
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second part of your question, of how to detect if a point is inside a polygon, is really a separate question.

Comment: Also this little article I just wrote up might be useful, it includes a way to make the polygon draggable too: http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/google-maps-api-draggable-polygons/